# Uploading Image to server with SOAP webservice

Tags: android, image, android-ksoap2

I get an error saying "Server was unable to process request. ---> Instance failure." when I try to upload an image with SOAP webservice.

Please help as I'm stuck here.

Here is my code:

```
private class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(UploadImageActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, baos);
        //bMap is the bitmap object
        byte[] imagebyte = baos.toByteArray();

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);          
        request.addProperty("Email", UserContext.email);
        request.addProperty("MobileNo", UserContext.mobilenumber);
        request.addProperty("Image", imagebyte);
        request.addProperty("Flage_InsertiedBy", UserContext.Flage_InsertiedBy);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            webResponse = response.toString();
            System.out.println("test response upload " + webResponse);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("test response upload ex " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return webResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: `request.addProperty("Image", imagebyte);`. Think you can only send text to soap server. Not bytes. The compiler will try to make a string out of the bytes by converting your code to `request.addProperty("Image", imagebyte.toString());`. But then not the contents of the byte array will be send as string but a string like ]@12345ade which is a java identifier for the array. Please print imagebyte.toString() to see.

Answer (score 0):

I convert the image to a Byte Array and process as. Works like a charm

```
String NAMESPACE = "http://Webservices.MyDomain.com/WebServices";    
String METHOD_NAME = "UploadRequestImage";   
String SOAP_ACTION = "http://Webservices.MyDomain.com/WebServices/UploadRequestImage";  
String URL = "http://webservices.MyDomain.com/webservices/UpdateData.asmx";              

SoapObject table = null;                        // Contains table of dataset that returned through SoapObject
SoapObject client = null;                        // Its the client petition to the web service         
SoapObject responseBody = null;                    // Contains XML content of dataset                 
SoapSerializationEnvelope sse = null;

sse = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
new MarshalBase64().register(sse); 
sse.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "movie", this.getClass());
//Note if class name isn't "movie" ,you must change 
sse.dotNet = true; // if WebService written .Net is result=true
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 600000);          

try {
    client = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    client.addProperty("TicketId", MyTicketId);     
    client.addProperty("UserId", UserId);       
    client.addProperty("imageBytes", ByteArray);    
    client.addProperty("FileName", "Image_" + SelectedId + ".jpg"); 
    sse.setOutputSoapObject(client);
    sse.bodyOut = client;
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, sse);

    // This step: get file XML
    responseBody = (SoapObject) sse.getResponse();
    // remove information XML,only retrieved results that returned

    responseBody = (SoapObject) responseBody.getProperty(1);
    // get information XMl of tables that is returned

    table = (SoapObject) responseBody.getProperty(0);

}//try block
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("ETC", e.getMessage());                      
    return null;
}//catch

return table;
```